# Bash output array from JSON object names

Tags: arrays, json, bash

I'm trying to extract object names from JSON so that I can iterate over them. Here's my JSON:

```
{
    "Resources": {
        "vpc": {
            "cidr": "192.168.1.0/24",
            "dns_resolution": "TRUE"
        },
        "subnet": {
            "cidr": "192.168.1.0/24",
            "availability_zone": "us-west-1a"
        }
    }
}
```

This should return an array, like this:

```
echo ${array[@]}
vpc subnet
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a JSON parser to achieve this.
You can use "jq", available on https://stedolan.github.io/jq/

You can play with it before installing it on https://jqplay.org/ , to check it will be able to do what you want, and to learn how.

Comment: Specifically, `cat yourdata.json | jq '.Resources | keys | join(" ")' -r` should give you the desired output in the original question.